# Change application language

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5. I tried to change the application language from English to German.
For that I modified in the config/app.php file the following two lines:

'locale' => 'de',

'fallback_locale' => 'de',

Further I added to the resource/lang two folders 'de' and 'en'.

After that, I output the application language in my view file:
Lang::getLocale() which allways show me 'en' as locale language instead of 'de'. Is there an other file which needs to be updated to de/german?

What Did I wrong? Thanks for suggestions! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config files are probably being cached,you should use `config:clear` to fix it

Answer (score -1):

## Laravel5-MultiLanguage

How to make multi language site on Laravel 5 with 3 steps
Test Source Git: https://github.com/edyrkaj/Laravel5-MultiLanguage

In this example are used to different languages (English and Albanian)
So on folder resources/lang i have putted to folders
 /al/.
 /en/.

You can test it with putting on browser url

For English
    localhost/language/en
For Albanian
    localhost/language/al

Language file used is resources/lang/[al|en]/demo.php

Thank you!